# Why this logic of absolute value doesn't work?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int A=1,B=4,C=3,D=3;

    int res1=A-B;

    int res2=B-D;

    if(res1<0){
        int res1=(-1)*res1;
        if(res1>=res2){
            printf("%d\n",res1);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the res1 as an absolute value(eg:-5 will be assigned as 5) but when execute the code there output terminal is blank. Please reply me want is wrong with my logic.

Comment: You have two different and separate variables named `res1`. The second is initialized using the *uninitialized* value of itself.

Comment: Also note that `-1 * variable` is exactly the same as `-variable`.

Comment: `int res1=(-1)*res1;` --> `res1=(-1)*res1;`

Answer (score 2):

The `if` block introduces inner scope and declaration of `res1` in the inner scope will *hide* the `res1` declared and defined in the outer scope. Within the `if` block wherever you use `res1`, it will be the `res1` declared in inner scope and **not** the one in the outer scope.

Also, in this statement of `if` block,

```
    int res1=(-1)*res1;
```

the uninitialised `res1` is used in the expression used to initialise it. In the context of your program, this is undefined behaviour *(curious to know why!, check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior/40674888#40674888)**).*

To fix the problem, either follow the suggestion given in the comment i.e. don't redeclare the `res1` in `if` block or you can also use standard library function `abs()` to get the absolute value of `res1`:

```
    if ((res1 < 0) && (abs(res1) >= res2)) {
        printf("%d\n", abs(res1));  //assuming you want to print absolute value of res1
    }
```

Note that, to use standard library function `abs()`, `stdlib.h` header file need to include in the program.